# how to publish an Android App Bundle in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

how to publish an Android App Bundle in the Google Play Console?

Environment: Android Studio 3.2

After "Generate Signed Bundle or APK", I got a file "app.aab".
How can I publish this file in Google Play Console and what is different between "Bundle" and APK?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can upload the App Bundle (.aab) file at the same place you used to upload your APKs in the Play Console. If this is an existing app, you will need to enroll in Play Signing first (Go to "App Releases" > "App Signing" in the Play Console) so that Google can sign the APKs it generates from the bundle.

The App Bundle allows Google to generate smaller and optimized APKs for your users by serving only the files they need for the device they have. See https://g.co/androidappbundle for more information.

Comment: Do you happen to know fi there are CI tools that support automated publishing of App Bundles? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57573083/56285

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Where do you upload files to Play?

Comment: Well it does for those who have uploaded APK before :) Go to "App Releases" page, then Manage track.

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me find it, it turned out that I was on the wrong console somehow, but googling for google play console releases got me the correct url.

If you're on the right site, it should be your app -> Production ->  and there should be a button in there.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en